# android- push notification only shows the last id

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have an application for creating routine task with push notification. when I add multiple tasks ( each one has a unique ID), and push notification appears it has the data of the last task.
I checked with LogCat and made sure that in **TaskActivity** each task has a unique ID but in **AlarmService** only the last task entered gets shown.

I search a lot and also but I couldn't find any clue about what have gone wrong.

I also changed  `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` to `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` and `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` but it did not work.

I thought about adding an `intent` for each task but I couldn't find a way to do it.

**TaskActivity**

```
   .
   .
   .
    public void setNotificationForNewTaskInside() {
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);

    Random random = new Random();
    randomNum= random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

     pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
             randomNum, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if (DeviceTimeAndDate.devicetaskTimeDate.equals(newtaskTimeDate)) {

       finalLong=System.currentTimeMillis();

        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, finalLong, pendingIntent);

    }
   else   if (DeviceTimeAndDate.devicetaskTimeDate.before(newtaskTimeDate)) {

       finalLong=new_task_timeInMilliseconds;
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, finalLong, pendingIntent);

    } else if (DeviceTimeAndDate.devicetaskTimeDate.after(newtaskTimeDate)) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "زمان یا تاریخ مورد گذشنه است، لطفا زمان دیگری را انتخاب کنید", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startDate.setText(DeviceTimeAndDate.deviceTime);
        taskTime.setText(EditTaskActivity.secondMiConver);
    }
```

**AlarmReciver**

```
 public class AlarmReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {
 String TAG = "AlarmReceiver";
  public RemoteViews remoteViews;
public  Uri sound;
public Context context;
public Notification notification;
int finalRandumNum;
 public  static String getTitle,getTime;
public AlarmReceiver (){
}

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/raw/plucky");
      remoteViews= new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.notif_image, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
      remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title,getTitle);
     remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text,getTime);

    NotificationManager notif=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    android.app.Notification notify=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "CHANNEL_ID")
            .setContentTitle(TaskActivity.subjEntry)
            .setWhen(finalLong)
            .setSound(sound)
            .setContentText(TaskActivity.timeEntryy)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(TaskActivity.pendingIntent)
            .build();

    notif.notify(TaskActivity.randomNum, notify);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making a mistake by saving the tasks details in a variable (**TaskActivity.subjEntry and TaskActivity.timeEntryy** ) which means the data is being replaced every time you try to add a new task.

So you should save your data in database, array or any other data structure and retrieve the data when creating notification.

## save data to SQlite DB

```
 public void addData(Data data){

    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv_data = new ContentValues();
    cv_data.put("key", data.key());
    cv_data.put("subjEntry", data.subjEntry());
    cv_data.put("subjTime", data.subjTime());

   database.insert("tablename",null,cv_data);
   database.close();
}
```

## Below is a code to retrieve data from SQLite database

```
   public List<Data> getData(String key){

    String columns [] = {
         "key", "subjEntry", "subjTime"
    };

    String sortingOrder = " subjTime ASC";

    List <Data> dataList = new ArrayList <Data>();

    SQLiteDatabase mdDatabase = getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = mdDatabase.query("tablename",
            columns,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            sortingOrder);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
        if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subjEntry")).equals(Key)){
        }
           Data data = new Data();
           data.setsubjEntry(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subjEntry")));
           data.setsubjTime(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subjTime")));
           dataList.add(data);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    mdDatabase.close();
    cursor.close();

    return dataList;
}'
```

Alternatively try  [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android)

Comment: I think I got it, thanks. I already save the data in the DB in `ContentValues (key, value)`  format. but I don't know how should I retrieve it. should I use a `Curser`?